# SVG turns to black square when converted to a font

Tags: css, svg

I have an image that I'm exporting from the app Nucleo as an SVG. If you look at the SVG in the browser, it looks good, but after running it through `svgtofont` it turns into a black box. The current repo has many SVGs, all of them render fine, just this one is problematic.

Here's the code for the SVG, is there something in there that's incompatible with turning it into a font?

```
<svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" version="1.1"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <title>asset</title>
    <g class="nc-icon-wrapper">
        <defs>
            <path d="M8 0c.558 0 1.01.452 1.01 1.009v1.069a5.97 5.97 0 0 1 4.909 4.913h1.072a1.009 1.009 0 1 1 0 2.018h-1.078a5.974 5.974 0 0 1-4.903 4.855v1.127a1.01 1.01 0 0 1-2.019 0v-1.132a5.975 5.975 0 0 1-4.853-4.85H1.01a1.009 1.009 0 1 1 0-2.018h1.122a5.974 5.974 0 0 1 4.859-4.909V1.009A1.01 1.01 0 0 1 8 0zm0 3.939a4.061 4.061 0 1 0 0 8.123 4.061 4.061 0 0 0 0-8.123zm0 2.07a1.992 1.992 0 1 1 .001 3.983 1.992 1.992 0 0 1 0-3.984z" id="path-1"/>
        </defs>
        <g id="Tracking" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
            <g id="&#x21B3;-&#x1F3A8;Color">
                <mask id="mask-2" fill="#fff">
                    <use xlink:href="#path-1"/>
                </mask>
                <use id="Mask" fill="#000" xlink:href="#path-1"/>
                <g id="Group" mask="url(#mask-2)" fill="#1B2431">
                    <g id="&#x21B3;-&#x1F3A8;Color">
                        <path id="Base" d="M0 0h16v16H0z"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: These IDs look pretty fruity `&#x21B3;-&#x1F3A8;Color` — what happens if you replace them?

Comment: Actually the whole lot is pretty complicated looking, are you able to "expand" the paths in Nucleo? You have multiple probably unneeded groups, as well as the path (`id="Base"` this is your black square) that uses a mask called `mask-2` that references a path called `path-1`, the syntax might be too complex for the svgtofont

Comment: To anyone who comes back to this post because of an overly complex SVG. I'm now using SVGO to optimize the SVGs before converting them to a font. Hopefully catching cases like this before they cause problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
<svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" version="1.1"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <title>asset</title>
<path d="M8 0c.558 0 1.01.452 1.01 1.009v1.069a5.97 5.97 0 0 1 4.909 4.913h1.072a1.009 1.009 0 1 1 0 2.018h-1.078a5.974 5.974 0 0 1-4.903 4.855v1.127a1.01 1.01 0 0 1-2.019 0v-1.132a5.975 5.975 0 0 1-4.853-4.85H1.01a1.009 1.009 0 1 1 0-2.018h1.122a5.974 5.974 0 0 1 4.859-4.909V1.009A1.01 1.01 0 0 1 8 0zm0 3.939a4.061 4.061 0 1 0 0 8.123 4.061 4.061 0 0 0 0-8.123zm0 2.07a1.992 1.992 0 1 1 .001 3.983 1.992 1.992 0 0 1 0-3.984z" id="path-1"/>
</svg>
```

The path in your example with an ID of `Base`uses this mask to cut itself out in a very contrived way. I just copied the mask path, and kept it as a path, and deleted everything else!

Demo:
https://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/bcde36ccc9e6b5b8a8e8e22cdaf58a2d

Every now and again I'm pleased I've messed around with SVG code!

Comment: Nailed it, renders now.